# How to make an multidimensional array with different types

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I would like to make a multidimensional arrays that will hold (in one row): string, int, bool, string.
I can do it using struct, but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that's possible, and even if it was, it wouldn't be pretty.  What's wrong using a struct/class to define the members of a single-dimensional array?

Comment: The only way to store different types in an array would be to use a common base type for the array, in this case `Object[]`. That is naturally pretty far from elegant. An array of a class is what you would use to get the strict typing of the values.

Comment: The struct *is* the more elegant solution. OOP is the way to go!

Comment: Structs are elegant...

Comment: You can use `DataTable`.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be

```
var values = new Tuple<string, int, bool, string>[10];
values[0] = Tuple.Create(str1, i, b, str2);
```

But a more elegant way would be just to create a class to encapsulate that data, and return an array (or maybe, just sequence, ie: IEnumerable).
Struct could be a bad idea if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If that array is a local variable in method, you can use anonymous class

```
var element = new { str1 = "a", i = 5, b = true, str2 = "b" };
var array = new [] { element };
```

But if this data used as field or method parameter, better to create a named class. The only way to put different types in same array is to cast them to common base type, which is Object in your case. Before doing so, imagine that some violent psychopath who knows where you live will have to maintain your code.